# create a rsa256 jwt with encode private key by java

Tags: java, jwt

I am trying to create an access token for line API
below is my private key 
{ 
"alg": "RS256", 
"d": "TC4Ij......wqSQIQ", 
"dp": "nJg12KiRo...nc02GdK-d8", 
"dq": "UzRtJ.....HA70", 
"e": "AQAB", 
"ext": true,
"key_ops": [
"sign"
],
"kty": "RSA",
"n": "rj_fXZ.....kuNDvOOHimw",
"p": "70k5HA_wTnmAEm.....z4pG79DZ5U",
"qi": "7j7gzQq....NfS7B8HRiC4"
}

I wanted to create a token by the the key with payload and header using the code below

```
String token = null;
        byte[] privateKey = ResourceUtil.readStr("line_key/privatekey-dev.json", StandardCharsets.UTF_8).getBytes();
        // ペイロードの設定
        Map<String, Object> payloadClaims = new HashMap<>();
        // line channel id
        payloadClaims.put("iss", "XXXXXXX");
        payloadClaims.put("sub", "XXXXXXX");
        payloadClaims.put("aud", "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX");
        payloadClaims.put("exp", new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + 60 * 30));
        payloadClaims.put("token_exp", 60 * 60 * 24 * 30);
        try {
            KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
            PKCS8EncodedKeySpec privSpec = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(privateKey);
            RSAPrivateKey privKey = (RSAPrivateKey) keyFactory.generatePrivate(privSpec);
            //Algorithm algorithm = Algorithm.RSA256(null, privKey);
            token = Jwts.builder()
                    .setHeaderParam("typ", "JWT")
                    .setHeaderParam("alg", "RS256")
                    .setHeaderParam("kid", "XXXXXXX").setClaims(payloadClaims)
                    .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.RS256, privKey) 
                    .compact();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error(e.getMessage());
        }
```

Since the private the not encoded so I didnt use Base64 to decode it.
But it always showed 
java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException: java.security.InvalidKeyException: invalid key format 
Even if I use Base64 to decode the private key read from the json file it didnt work.

```
byte[] keyContentAsBytes = Base64.getMimeDecoder().decode(privateKey);
```

Can any body tell me how to solve this issue. 
Thanks

PS: jwt can be generated by python with

```
key = RSAAlgorithm.from_jwk(privateKey)
JWT = jwt.encode(payload, key, algorithm="RS256", headers=headers, json_encoder=None)
```

Comment: *Since the private the not encoded so I didnt use Base64 to decode it.* How can it *not* be encoded if you've got it in a json format? You do know that keys are binary values and not json-able characters..?

Comment: @g00se thanks for the replay. so you mean I need to decode it but even I used the source below it still didn't work                                                                                 
 String privateKey = ResourceUtil.readStr("line_key/privatekey-dev.json",   StandardCharsets.UTF_8).replaceAll("/n", "");  
byte[] keyContentAsBytes = Base64.getMimeDecoder().decode(privateKey);
PKCS8EncodedKeySpec privSpec = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(keyContentAsBytes); 
RSAPrivateKey privKey = (RSAPrivateKey) keyFactory.generatePrivate(privSpec);

Comment: You should probably be using a special api to do this. Possibly [this](https://simplesolution.dev/java-json-web-token-using-java-jwt-library/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, because you are re-inventing the date-arithmetic wheel, your token will only be valid for 1.8 seconds. I doubt that's what you intended. Use higher level APIs from `java.time` instead of magic numbers and obsolete types from `java.util` so that your code states the intent clearly.

You don't have a PKCS-#8–encoded key spec, so you can't use `PKCS8EncodedKeySpec`. For some reason I can't fathom, JWK ignored existing standards like PKCS #8 and invented a new format with a bloated yet still opaque JSON encoding.

If you really need to convert the private key yourself, you can get the parameters from the JWK and create a [`RSAPrivateCrtKeySpec`.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/security/spec/RSAPrivateCrtKeySpec.html) I say "really," because I'd be surprised if the library you are using doesn't have some means to load a `PrivateKey` from a JWK representation.

Here is the mapping between JWK RSA private key members and Java's `RSAPrivateCrtKeySpec` properties.

| JWK member | RSAPrivateCrtKeySpec property |
| --- | --- |
| n | modulus |
| e | publicExponent |
| d | privateExponent |
| p | primeP |
| q | primeQ |
| dp | primeExponentP |
| dq | primeExponentQ |
| qi | crtCoefficient |

Base-64 decode each value in the JWK, then create a `BigInteger` with the resulting magnitude, specifying the sign is positive: `new BigInteger(+1, magnitude)`. Instantiate a `RSAPrivateCrtKeySpec` and use that with your `KeyFactory` in place of the `PCKS8EncodedKeySpec`.